# Setting up a subnetted Cisco WAN - Serial connection doesn't work

Tags: cisco, routing, subnet, wide-area-network, rip

I have two routers setup on subnetted on a network address of 192.168.25.0/29 and I can't seem to get the serial connection to work with RIP. Here are the running-config for the two routers:

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1410739/1.txt
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1410739/2.txt
```

The FastEthernet interfaces work, and I've double checked that I'm using the right Serial ports. I'm a beginner but I'm confident it's just a misconfiguration.

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. I didn't include a clock rate for the serial interfaces. Phew!